# KafkaSpout (idle) generates a huge network traffic

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-storm

After developing and executing my Storm (1.0.1) topology with a KafkaSpout and a couple of Bolts, I noticed a huge network traffic even when the topology is idle (no message on Kafka, no processing is done in bolts). So I started to comment out my topology piece by piece in order to find the cause and now I have only the KafkaSpout in my main:

```
....
final SpoutConfig spoutConfig = new SpoutConfig(
                new ZkHosts(zkHosts, "/brokers"), 
                "files-topic", // topic
                "/kafka", // ZK chroot 
                "consumer-group-name");
     spoutConfig.scheme = new SchemeAsMultiScheme(new StringScheme());
     spoutConfig.startOffsetTime = OffsetRequest.LatestTime();
     topologyBuilder.setSpout(
                        "kafka-spout-id, 
                        new KafkaSpout(config),
                        1); 
....
```

When this (useless) topology executes, even in local mode, even the very first time, the network traffic always grows a lot: I see (in my Activity Monitor)

- An average of 432 KB of data received/sec
- After a couple of hours the topology is running (idle) data received is 1.26GB and data sent is 1GB

[image]

(Important: Kafka is not running in cluster, a single instance that runs in the same machine with a single topic and a single partition. I just downloaded Kafka on my machine, started it and created a simple topic. When I put a message in the topic, everything in the topology is working without any problem at all)

Obviously, the reason is in the `KafkaSpout.nextTuple()` method (below), but I don't understand why, without any message in Kafka, I should have such traffic. Is there something I didn't consider? Is that the expected behaviour? I had a look at Kafka logs, ZK logs, nothing, I have cleaned up Kafka and ZK data, nothing, still the same behaviour.

```
@Override
public void nextTuple() {
    List<PartitionManager> managers = _coordinator.getMyManagedPartitions();
    for (int i = 0; i < managers.size(); i++) {

        try {
            // in case the number of managers decreased
            _currPartitionIndex = _currPartitionIndex % managers.size();
            EmitState state = managers.get(_currPartitionIndex).next(_collector);
            if (state != EmitState.EMITTED_MORE_LEFT) {
                _currPartitionIndex = (_currPartitionIndex + 1) % managers.size();
            }
            if (state != EmitState.NO_EMITTED) {
                break;
            }
        } catch (FailedFetchException e) {
            LOG.warn("Fetch failed", e);
            _coordinator.refresh();
        }
    }

    long diffWithNow = System.currentTimeMillis() - _lastUpdateMs;

    /*
         As far as the System.currentTimeMillis() is dependent on System clock,
         additional check on negative value of diffWithNow in case of external changes.
     */
    if (diffWithNow > _spoutConfig.stateUpdateIntervalMs || diffWithNow < 0) {
        commit();
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you ask your question also on the storm-user mailing list?

Comment: Yes, I was trying here before because I'm not sure if the matter is more on the Kafka or Storm side

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Put a sleep for one second (1000ms) in the nextTuple() method and observe the traffic now, For example,

```
@Override
public void nextTuple() {
   try {
       Thread.sleep(1000);
   } catch(Exception ex){
        log.error("Ëxception while sleeping...",e);
   }
   List<PartitionManager> managers = _coordinator.getMyManagedPartitions();
   for (int i = 0; i < managers.size(); i++) {
     ...
     ...
     ...
     ...
}
```

---

The reason is, kafka consumer works on the basis of [pull methodology](http://kafka.apache.org/documentation.html#design_pull) which means, consumers will pull data from kafka brokers. So in consumer point of view (Kafka Spout) will do a fetch request to the kafka broker continuously which is a [TCP network request](https://kafka.apache.org/protocol.html). So you are facing a huge statistics on the data packet sent/received. `Though the consumer doesn't consumes any message, pull request and empty response also will get account into network data packet sent/received statistics.` Your network traffic will be less if your sleeping time is high.  There are also some [network related configurations](http://kafka.apache.org/documentation.html#configuration) for the brokers and also for consumer. Doing the research on configuration may helps you. Hope it will helps you.

Comment: I ended with your same conclusions: I created a KafkaSpout decorator with a configurable sleep time before decoratee.nextTuple() is called. Putting a 10 msecs of delay reduces the network traffic 10 times (!). Thx for the answer

Answer (score 0):

Is your bolt receiving messages ? Do your bolt inherits BaseRichBolt ?

Comment out that line m.fail(id.offset) in Kafaspout and check it out. If your bolt doesn't ack then your spout assumes that message is failed and try to replay the same message.

```
public void fail(Object msgId) {
        KafkaMessageId id = (KafkaMessageId) msgId;
        PartitionManager m = _coordinator.getManager(id.partition);
        if (m != null) {
            //m.fail(id.offset);
        }
```

Also try halt the nextTuple() for few millis and check it out.

Let me know if it helps

Comment: Hi, many thanks for the response. Unfortunately I commented out my bolts...in the topology there's only the KafkaSpout and I'm not sending any message to Kafka. I'm debugging the KafkaSpout, it is just (correctly) fetching from Kafka a zero-msgs payload...but it seems this thing (done continuously in nextTuple) causes such huge traffic (and I'm not understanding why)

Comment: can you play with this stuff and check it out      spoutConfig.startOffsetTime = OffsetRequest.LatestTime(); // -1, -2 kafkaConfig.forceStartOffsetTime(-1)...(-2) for latest and earliest offsets..

Comment: Not sure I actually got you. But in ZK no consumer state is recorded as the Kafka Spout never consumed a message so I see the (transient) offset is set to -1. If I uncomment my bolts and then I put one message in the topic, the whole tuple tree is processed and after that I can see the consumer state recorded in ZK (offset = 1). So everything works as expected from a functional point of view...only that damned traffic jam which is still there